# Importing Parse to android studio

Tags: android, parsing, android-studio, emulation

I'm having trouble importing parse to Android Studio. After copying the SDK files to the libs folder and adding the compile commands to build.gradle and syncing the project, it messes up the emulator. I am able to modify the XML of the emulator, but when I run the app, the emulator doesn't display any changes whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add anything to the **libs** directory. Just add the following dependencies  to your **build.gradle** file

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
}
```

then click on **Sync now** and it will import everything automatically.

Comment: After doing this, will I see the imported files in the libs folder?

Comment: No, not in libs, the files will be in External Libraries.